# String reverse in VB Script without using Built in functions

Tags: string, vbscript

```
 option explicit

dim r, res, num

num= cint(inputbox("Enter the number"))

  do while(num > 0)

 r= num mod 10

 num= num\10

res= res & r

loop

msgbox res
```

Well this is the code, now my question is this works perfectly fine for input 1234, well if the input is 0123 it just prints 321 which is wrong.It needs to print 3210. 
I am unable to figure out, tried a lot but in vain, any help would be appreciated 
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

You must decide whether you want to reverse **strings** or **numbers** (accidentially represented as decimals). If you want to reverse strings, you should

1. not convert the (string) input to a number/integer
2. use string ops: Mid() for reading, concatenation & for building

**Added: In (demo/not production) code:**

```
Option Explicit

Function rev(s)
  Dim p
  For p = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
      rev = rev & Mid(s, p, 1)
  Next
End Function

Dim s
For Each s In Array("1234", "0123")
    WScript.Echo s, rev(s)
Next
```

output:

```
1234 4321
0123 3210
```

Comment: Well what if the input is  taken as  `num= "1234"`

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: Well appreciate your help on this, is it not possible doing this without **any** functions/ built in functions what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim   num,   rev
num   =   inputbox("Enter a number")
If   Len(num)=4 Then
rev = rev*10 + num mod 10
num = num/10
num = left(num,3)
rev = rev*10 + num mod 10
num = num/10
num = left(num,2)
rev = rev*10 + num mod 10
num = num/10
num = left(num,1)
rev = rev*10 + num mod 10
msgbox "Reverse Order of the number is "&rev 
Else
msgbox "Number, you entered is not a 4 digit number"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

String reverse program without using Reverse String function & Mid function.

```
str=inputbox("Enter the string: ")
str1=len(str)
a=Left(str,1)
for i=1 to str1
str2=Left(str,i)
if len(str2)>1 then
   str3=Right(str2,1)&temp
   temp=str3    
end if
next
msgbox temp&a
```

Answer (score 0):

str = Inputbox("Enter the number")

rev=""

Set regx = New RegExp

regx.Global = True

regx.IgnoreCase = True

regx.Pattern = ".{1}"

Set colchars= regx.Execute(str)

For i = 0 To colchars.Count-1

rev= colchars.Item(i)&rev

Next

MsgBox rev

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function mno()
a = "Ram is a good boy"
length = Len(a)
b = Right(a, 1)
For i = 1 To length Step 1
c = Left(a, length - i)
d = Right(c, 1)
b = b & d
Next
Debug.Print a
Debug.Print b
End Function
```

Comment: You should add explanation.